# Magento 2: where is located checkout/success.phtml

Tags: magento2

I want to add tracking code to last step checkout success.phtml

This file should be:

```
app/design/frontend/THEME/THEME_NAME/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml
```

but here I have only folder:

```
Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/
```

- coupon.phtml

  - form.phtml
  - minicart.phtml
  - shipping.phtml

@Wisam

I have found code in

```
app/design/frontend/THEME/THEME_NAME/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml
```

and here I have added google tracking code.

What do you think about this? Will it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have this file in your theme, that's mean the file is coming from the core module,

check this path

> vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates

you will find the **success.phtml** inside this folder, Copy this file to your path

> app/design/frontend/THEME/THEME_NAME/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml

Refresh the cache, then modify it as you wish

Comment: I have update my topic.

Comment: It is very important to do some test, Try to place order then try to use inspect element in the browser and search for your code to insure that the code is exist and the success.phtml taking from right place